# How to calculate one hour ago time from an string array in java which holds value from database

Tags: java, arrays, time

I have an array of string type which holds values from database which are in the format "2014-09-02 15:19:59.000".Array has 3600 rows .now I want to calculate one hour ago time from these values in java.How to do that. 
Code for selection for retrieval of values from database  is:

```js
public String[] database_Current() {
  List < String > timeStr = new ArrayList < String > ();


  try {
    con = getConnection();
    String sql = "select max(logtime) from vacuum_analog_1mins";

    clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql);

    clstmt.execute();
    rs = clstmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {

      timeStr.add(rs.getString(1).substring(11, 16));

    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean in getDbTable(String code):" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection();
  }
  // I would return the list here, but let's convert it to an array
  atime = timeStr.toArray(new String[timeStr.size()]);





  return atime;
}
```

How to get one hour time ago from atime values.

Comment: the date/time should have been stored in milliseconds, measured in milliseconds between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC . Also see this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12/3879470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using Joda DateTime for manipulating dates, here's a debate about it https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190891/joda-time-vs-java-time

for what concerns your question, the following snippet:

```
String sDate = "2014-09-02 15:19:59.000";
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.parse(sDate,
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format));
System.out.println( oDate.minusHours(1).toString(format));
```

prints

> 2014-09-02 14:19:59.000

the imports

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
```

---

If you cannot use DateTime, the solution using only java.util would be as  kriyeta suggests, just some fixes:

```
String sDate = "2014-09-02 15:19:59.000";
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";    
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(sDate);
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date); 
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
hours--; 
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
Date fixedDate=calendar.getTime(); 
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(fixedDate));
```

With respect to the comment, to have the output look the same you need to align the formats so either

```
System.out.println(date + "-" + fixedDate); // Tue Sep 02 15:19:59 CEST 2014-Tue Sep 02 14:19:59 CEST 2014
```

or

```
 System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date) + "-" + simpleDateFormat.format(fixedDate)); // 2014-09-02 15:19:59.000-2014-09-02 14:19:59.000
```

but you have a complete control over how the dates are represented as strings, so don't let that confuse you, the only important thing is to get your Date instances right

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE .When I import then message that The import org.joda cannot be resolved is shown.

Comment: yes its a third-party lib, you would have to download joda-datetime jar and place on classpath, added a java util solution only as well, just in case you don't won't to use third-party libs

Comment: @MasterSlave you shouldn't give same answer. Think something different.

Comment: :) the same but fixed you'r bug, setHours, getHours, and the wrong format, anyways, a vote-up for you and a plee to SRY_JAVA to accept yours, if it fixes his issue :)

Comment: @MasterSlave okay. no probs.

Comment: @MasterSlave when I do as u said then time is showing one hour previous time but there is some mistake in date parameter,My out put is: _"previos date odf db is Thu Jan 02 15:19:59 IST 2014
current date odf db is 2014-09-02 16:19:59.0 "_.I want previous date also in the same format as current database date.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is little bit confusing. In your question, you are getting only single row from query **`"select max(logtime) from vacuum_analog_1mins"`** that contains **max(logtime)** single column and that single value you are storing in timeStr array. I didn't get what the purpose of using array here to store single value even if you will get single value every time.

What i got is you want to have time one hour less than actual time getting from database.

example:

getting from database:

```
currentDateFromDB = 2014-09-02 15:19:59.000
```

you want to have:

```
changedDate = 2014-09-02 14:19:59.000
```

For This you can use Calendar class of java as:

```
//currentDateFromDB in string form from db
Date parsedDate = new Date();
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    parsedDate = format.parse(currentDateFromDB);
}
catch(ParseException pe) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(parsedDate); //set date here
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
hours--; //reduce by one
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours); //again set desired hours
Date date=calendar.getTime(); //get modified time
```

Comment: My values from database are in array.How to convert this array into calender.Moreover when I do as u did it ,then the following error is shown 'The method set(int, int) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (int)' and the The constructor Date(String) is deprecated.

Comment: when I do as u said then one hour previous time is shown but there is some mistake in date parameter,My out put is: _'previous date of db is Thu Jan 02 15:19:59 IST 2014
current date of db is 2014-09-02 16:19:59.0'_.I want previous date also in the same format as current database date.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA You can use SimpleDateFormat(format) to format your date as you want.

Comment: I have used SimpleDateFormat(format).Some of my code is :_'String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";    
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
  Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timestr);
  Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(date); 
  
System.out.println("previous date is"+(fixedDate));
System.out.println("current date is"+timestr);
return fixedDate;'_.   But then also my output is:_'previous date isTue Sep 02 15:19:59 IST 2014
current date is 2014-09-02 16:19:59.0'_.How to change the format of previous date.